# Configure dataset for Access database with multiple count columns on the same field

Tags: sql, ms-access, reporting-services, rdlc, reportbuilder

I have this SQL so far and it works fine. For background this is the query from trying to configure a xsd dataset that relates to an access database and I'm working on it in VS report builder to make reports. People holds info on people, SessionsLogged holds info on activities run where ID is for each specific session but SessionID is more like the type of activity so you get multiple IDs for each SessionID, the tables are linked by the PeopleSessions table:

```
SELECT People.AriadneNo, People.Forename, People.Surname, People.Gender, People.MobileNo, Countries.Country, COUNT(SessionsLogged.ID) AS CountOfID, SessionsLogged.SessionID, People.EmailAddress
FROM     (((SessionsLogged INNER JOIN
                  PeopleSessions ON SessionsLogged.ID = PeopleSessions.SLID) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  People ON PeopleSessions.PersonID = People.ID) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Countries ON People.Country = Countries.ID)
WHERE  (SessionsLogged.SessionID IN (1))
GROUP BY People.AriadneNo, People.Forename, People.Surname, People.Gender, People.MobileNo, Countries.Country, SessionsLogged.SessionID, People.EmailAddress
```

At the moment I can get a report from this that gives me details of every person who attended any instance of a selected activity plus the number of times they have attended the activity. I would like to modify this so I can get details of every person who attended any one of 5 selected activities and then 5 columns which show the number of times they attended each type of activity. I have tried using CASE but this gave me an error (I think because it's an access database?), I've also attempted IIF and subqueries but I either did it wrong (probable) or they don't work because either way the dataset told me I'd done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you expected you can create a calculated variable for each SessionID of interest.  Here is the sql for my mock data where I made CountSession1 and Countsession2.  In words If SessionID is 1 CountSessionID is 1 otherwise 0 and we sum rather than count the result.  Ignore the right joins that is just how I set up the mock data,
[image]
here is the resulting sql:

```
SELECT People.ForeName, People.SurName, SessionsLogged.SessionID, Sum(IIf([SessionsLogged].[SessionID]=1,1,0)) AS CountSession1, Sum(IIf([SessionsLogged].[SessionID]=2,1,0)) AS CountSession2
FROM SessionsLogged INNER JOIN ((Countries RIGHT JOIN People ON Countries.ID = People.Country) RIGHT JOIN PeopleSessions ON People.ID = PeopleSessions.PersonID) ON SessionsLogged.ID = PeopleSessions.SLID
GROUP BY People.ForeName, People.SurName, SessionsLogged.SessionID;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it's not working for me since I'm trying to make a dataset in Visual Studio with the tableAdapter wizard/ query builder and it doesn't seem to accept IIf statements

Comment: sorry I missed the rdlc tag and my visual studio seems to be messed up so I can't help for now